# Reading log files from zip file using logstash-forwarding

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder

I am using logstash-forwarder to send the logs to logstash server using lumberjack input plugin.

One of my requirement is to read logs from old archived .ZIP files using logstash-forwarder.
I tried to use .zip in my configuration file as follows

```
"files": [
    {
      "paths": ["C:\\jboss-eap-6.1.0.Alpha\\standalone\\log\\**\\*.zip"
     }
 ]
```

But it is not working.

Please let me know, if it is possible to read logs from .ZIP file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Filebeat is the replacement of logstash-forwarder. Both don't support the feature but there is an open issue for this: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/637 I recommend you to follow the issue for further details and progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logstash-forwarder is really designed to send the latest log information to logstash.  It's basically doing a 'tail -f' of your log file, and sending the new stuff.  As such, it (and most shippers) don't handle gzip'ed files.

One option is to unzip them and send them.

There's also a gzip_lines codec that you can install, though I wasn't able to get it to work under logstash 1.5.

The S3 input filter handles zipped files (since it knows you're not streaming from S3).

Comment: Yes you are are right, there is no way to read from archived zip files.